# Combine and adjust characters in a new column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to create a new column that combines characters from two existing columns. My df currently looks like this:

```
ID                Town
AK_Town_0233470   Hooper Bay
CA_Town_0603330   Avilla Beach
CA_Town_0616462   Corte Madera
CA_Town_0623042   Eureka
CA_Town_0625338   Foster City
```

And I'm trying to make a new column (New_ID) that looks like this:

```
ID                Town           New_ID
AK_Town_0233470   Hooper Bay     Hooper Bay, AK
CA_Town_0603330   Avilla Beach   Avilla Beach, CA
CA_Town_0616462   Corte Madera   Corte Madera, CA
CA_Town_0623042   Eureka         Eureka, CA
CA_Town_0625338   Foster City    Foster City, CA
```

I think tidyverse unite might help, but I'm not simply uniting the columns, but adding parts of the ID column to the Town column, and including a comma.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, using `paste` and some string-manipulation/regex. What have you tried yourself so far? Please share your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `paste` and `substr` will easily do it like below:

```
df <- read.table(stringsAsFactor = FALSE, header=TRUE, sep = ",", 
                 text = 
"ID,                Town
AK_Town_0233470,   Hooper Bay
CA_Town_0603330,  Avilla Beach
CA_Town_0616462,   Corte Madera
CA_Town_0623042,   Eureka
CA_Town_0625338,   Foster City")

# Construct new ID using paste
df$new_id <- paste0(df$Town, ", ", substr(df$ID, 1,2))
print(df)
#               ID            Town              new_id
#1 AK_Town_0233470      Hooper Bay      Hooper Bay, AK
#2 CA_Town_0603330    Avilla Beach    Avilla Beach, CA
#3 CA_Town_0616462    Corte Madera    Corte Madera, CA
#4 CA_Town_0623042          Eureka          Eureka, CA
#5 CA_Town_0625338     Foster City     Foster City, CA
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Note that `paste0` and `paste` are basically the same just with the difference that the former uses no separator (`""`) as default and the latter uses a space (`" "`) as separator.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar approach to Anders above, but I used the `mutate` function from `dplyr`.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("AK_Town_0233470", "CA_Town_0603330", "CA_Town_0616462", 
                        "CA_Town_0623042", "CA_Town_0625338"), 
                 Town = c("Hooper Bay", "Avilla Beach", "Corte Madera", "Eureka", "Foster City"))

df %>% 
   mutate(New_ID = paste0(Town, ", ", str_extract(df$ID, pattern = "[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]")))
```

This is the result:

> ```
>           ID         Town           New_ID
> 1 AK_Town_0233470   Hooper Bay   Hooper Bay, AK
> 2 CA_Town_0603330 Avilla Beach Avilla Beach, CA
> 3 CA_Town_0616462 Corte Madera Corte Madera, CA
> 4 CA_Town_0623042       Eureka       Eureka, CA
> 5 CA_Town_0625338  Foster City  Foster City, CA
> ```

I used the `str_extract` function from the `stringr` package (also within the `tidyverse`) rather than `substr()` from base R but it will work, too.

```
df %>% 
   mutate(New_ID = paste0(Town, ", ", substr(df$ID, 1, 2)))
```